# Cinect WCF to WebService method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have WebService hosted on IIS at adress: `http://localhost:4100/FilesService.asmx` and in this service there is method:

```
[WebMethod]
        public dataModel.FileInfo AddFileInBase64(string ObjectType, string objectInBase64) //AuthenticationData
        {
         ...some code...
        }
```

And I hve WCF service that receive some data, from that WCF service I whant to send that data to Web Service, so i add service reference to `http://localhost:4100/FilesService.asmx?wsdl` and it is done corectly, in file `WebConfig` it adding:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Service1Soap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="Service1Soap12">
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
        messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/FilesService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1Soap"
    name="Service1Soap" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/FilesService.asmx" binding="customBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap12" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1Soap"
    name="Service1Soap12" />
</client>
```

but when I whant to do:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient sc = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
sc.AddFileInBase64("type", Convert.ToBase64String(dataByteArray));
```

in my WCF .svc.cs I get:

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references 
contract 'ServiceReference1.Service1Soap' in the ServiceModel client
configuration section. This might be because no configuration file
was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
this contract could be found in the client element.
```

`ServiceReference1.Service1Soap` is a interface:

[image]
[image]

Any idea why this probllem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your codes. it is not clear if `'ServiceReference1.Service1Soap'` is the interface or the the implementation itself.

So, if it's not Interface of your wcf service then you should change it to your wcf service interface name.

Answer (score 0):

You have Two Endpoint , u need to define which endpoint u want to use

```
ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient sc = new     ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService1SoapClient");
sc.AddFileInBase64("type", Convert.ToBase64String(dataByteArray));
```

Comment: tried this, also: "Service1Soap", "Service1Soap12", "ServiceReference1.Service1Soap" it did not help @edit: I also deleted one of endPoint, still this same

Comment: I can add that method where I using this reference has property: [OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{fileName}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)] if this change anything